# React JS socket on event doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have an Express.js backend and a React front end.

I install the `socket.io` on the backend.

App.js

```js
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port, ${port} ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
});

const io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('connected',socket.id)
  socket.on('infoListUpdate', function () {
    socket.broadcast.emit('updateInfoList');
    console.log('jj')
  });
  socket.on('docsListUpdate', function () {
    socket.broadcast.emit('updateDocsList',{});
    console.log('emited')
  });
});
```

In React I have

Company.js

```js
export default function Company(props) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Agent {...props} />
      <CreateDocs {...props} />
      <CreateInfo {...props} />
     
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

In the `CreateDocs` component, I do this

```
 socket.emit('docsListUpdate')
```

Then I can see the "emitted" is printing on the console.log of the backend. So I think emitting from the front end to the backend part is working.

Then Agent component I added this to listen to that event

```
 socket.on('updateDocsList',(data)=>{
    console.log('i am here')
  })
```

`"i am here"` part is never printing.

In the React front end, I created a `socket.js` file and import the socket from that file to the components.

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const baseURL =process.env.REACT_APP_BE_URL;

const socket = io.connect(baseURL,{
    transports:['websocket']
})

export default socket;
```

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I change this `socket.broadcast.emit('updateDocsList',{});`
to `socket.emit('updateDocsList',{});`

Reason:- Broadcast will emit for all except to the sender.